# My objects duplicate each other in django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, jinja2

I'm trying to do my Django web-app and can't to overcome a problem. I need to split my model objects on two divs for correct display, but my dish objects just duplicate each other. I've tried to find info how to split my dishes objects on two parts and give them to html code, but it didn't works. Also there is can be a python templates solution, but I don't know how to resolve it, because the pure html code of project is something I never seen before (there is left-list and right-list classes for dishes columns, therefore we need to split our dishes dict somehow). There is 2 for loops because of the first row tag creates two col-lg-6 on left and right sides (this can be seen in the last image of page code of default template), maybe it's a bad idea.

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import ReserveForm
from .models import ChefsModel, DishesModel

# Create your views here.

def reserve(request):
    chefs = ChefsModel.objects.all()
    dishes = DishesModel.objects.all()
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReserveForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            error = 'Invalid form'
    else:
        form = ReserveForm()

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form':form, 'error':error,
                'chefs':chefs, 'dishes':dishes, 'n':[1,2]})

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return reserve(request)
```

My Django template + HTML:

```
<article id='tabs-1'>
        <div class="row">
            {% for i in n %}
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="{% cycle 'left' 'right' %}-list">
                            {% for dish in dishes %}
                                {% if dish.tabs == 'Breakfast' %}
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="tab-item">
                                            <img src="{{ dish.image.url }}" alt="">
                                            <h4>{{ dish.name }}</h4>
                                            <p>{{ dish.description }}</p>
                                            <div class="price">
                                                <h6>${{ dish.price }}</h6>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </article>
```

How it is works in pure HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <section class='tabs-content'>
        <article id='tabs-1'>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="left-list">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="tab-item">
                                    <img src="assets/images/tab-item-01.png" alt="">
                                    <h4>Fresh Chicken Salad</h4>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur koit adipiscing elit, sed do.</p>
                                    <div class="price">
                                        <h6>$10.50</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="tab-item">
                                    <img src="assets/images/tab-item-02.png" alt="">
                                    <h4>Orange Juice</h4>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur koit adipiscing elit, sed do.</p>
                                    <div class="price">
                                        <h6>$8.50</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="tab-item">
                                    <img src="assets/images/tab-item-03.png" alt="">
                                    <h4>Fruit Salad</h4>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur koit adipiscing elit, sed do.</p>
                                    <div class="price">
                                        <h6>$9.90</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[Result of my HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAeUL.png)

[How it should be (in pure HTML)1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNZIf.png)

[How it should be (in pure HTML)2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgv9m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `{% for i in n %}` line is causing this problem because you then loop through all of your dishes in each n for-loop. The layout is more of a HTML/CSS problem which can probably be solved with a grid layout.

Comment: So, it means that there is no backend solution?

Comment: I don’t think it’s something you want to control with python but with HTML/CSS instead. If you want to do it in the template still then remove the first forloop and instead put an if statement with forloop.counter to put a row in every few loops

Comment: @oleqich you repeat `{% for dish in dishes %}` n times. That's how you implemented your template. What did you mean by `{% for i in n %}` around loop mentioned before? `dishes` are the same each `i` iteration.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I just don't know how to track the dishes remains at the current iteration of for. My for i in n cycle is definitely bad idea, I've undersood it. It's just my first independent work. If you have a documentation for this case, I'll be so glad to learn it)

Comment: @0sVoid Will it track of the dishes dict remains and put new dish objects in the left/right-list? If so, how did it work (if you have a documentation for this, pls share it)?

Comment: I would use `{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 %}` to insert a new row after every two dictionary items. If you want them to populate into left and right columns then you could do a similar thing but split them when you've gone through half of the dict